# C++ Function template to abstract function argument conversion

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I'm using Mono to embed C# in a C++ application and it has a function `mono_add_internal_call` used to invoke C/C++ from C#. The function receives a function pointer for the function it should call when the corresponding C# function is invoked.

One problem is, some types provided by the mono runtime are different from the ones I use in my functions (e.g. `MonoString*` instead of `char*`), and I was looking into a way to create an adapter function using templates that would abstract the type conversion of the arguments and return type.

The template would detect the type of each argument of my function, and return a lambda that would receive the corresponding mono arguments. When the lambda was invoked it would convert the types (e.g. `MonoString*` -> `char*`), and then invoke my function with the converted types as arguments.

This way I would not need to write a lambda for each function, like this:

```
bool myFunc(const std::string& s, int n);
mono_add_internal_call("CSharpClass.myFunc", [](MonoString* s, int) {
        myFunc(monoStrToChar(s));
    });
```

I would do something like this:

```
customInternalCall("CSharpClass.myFunc", myFunc);
```

This would also enable a way to invoke functions in object instances by passing the pointer as the first argument from the C# code.

```
EmbedType<MyClass> myType()
    .customInternalCall("CSharpClass.myFunc1", myFunc1) //receives the ptr in the first arg then would call ptr->myFunc1()
    .customInternalCall("CSharpClass.myFunc2", myFunc2);
```

I was able to get a list of the argument types and the return type of my functions, but I'm new to templates and now I'm stuck.

Is this possible? If so please provide an example.

Comment: The template part is relatively easy. The fundamental problem is that you need to manufacture a plain old function pointer that somehow needs to remember another function pointer (the function to be called) - but there's no natural place to store this state. This is usually done by generating a thunk in machine code on the fly (difficult and non-portable), or by maintaining a global wrapper-to-wrappee mapping.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thanks! I managed to do it by having a template struct that receives the function signature as a template parameter and it has a static variable of the function pointer. It also has the function that will be invoke by mono. I don't have the part of the conversions yet tho. Btw, do you know if the compiler can "merge" the template structs that have the same function signature? That would be a problem because of the static pointer in each template "instance".

Comment: Yes, you will only have one instantiation of the struct with a particular set of template parameters, and one copy of its static member, no matter how many times in how many translation units this instantiation occurs.